# How can I change the color of Terminal's shell prompt and create new empty line entering after a command?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, color

I am trying to permanently change the bash prompt color to blue as well as create a new empty line after I run my command to make the terminal easier to read.

Before I tried to make changes, I had `PS1="\n$PS1"`. I currently have `PS1="\e[0;34m[\u@ \W]\$ \e[m"` after my aliases in my .bash_profile but it's not giving me the behavior I want. When I'm writing a command and it reaches the end of the line before I finish, the terminal doesn't move on to the next line. Instead, it goes back to the beginning of the line I was working on and visually overwrites the bash prompt and anything after as I keep typing. How can I get the terminal to move onto a new line when it reaches the end of the previous line as well as make an empty line before/after every command?

Later realized I was looking at a guide for changing color of shell prompt for Linux when it should've been for Mac.

Comment: Escape codes in prompts work the same way in Linux terminals and in macOS Terminal/iTerm.

Comment: What about using Oh My Zsh with a theme?